# Laravel: Passing {id} in href

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am trying to pass the user id in the href link as below:-

**app.blade.php**

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('user.profile', $user->id)}}">Profile </a>
```

**app.php**

```
Route::get('user/profile/{id}', 'UserProfileController@profile')->name('user.profile');
```

**controller UserProfileController.js**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User; 

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => [ 'profile']]);
    }
    public function profile($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('user.profile', compact('user') );
    }

}
```

**The Error**

> Undefined variable: user (View: /home/riwaj/Desktop/dmt-intern-manager/InternManager/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

[image: SS of error]

Comment: So, where did you define `$user`?

Comment: @El_Vanja I have edited the question and added the controller part.

Comment: This is `app` blade template, you send that variable to `user.profile` blade template.

Comment: @El_Vanja What should I do? Change the home controller. Is there a way I can send the variable to app.blade template?

Comment: @RiwajChalise like it said **$user is undefined**. double check the root/master/single page that is using the undefined variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare id implicitly:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('user.profile', ['id' => $user->id])}}">Profile </a>
```

Comment: He will still get the same error I suppose because $user is not available in app.blade.php

Comment: @Vishal like you said. what could be the solution?

Comment: I'm no expert but as per my understanding it's a bad design app.blade.php is master layout file so this link should not be defined in master layout file directly...Can you show route for '/home' which controller method it calls

Comment: If you need user in your app.blade.php file you can use View Composer to provide user there, but if you provide user for app.blade.php remember that you can not use this file for guest users. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers